# Compiling and linking CUDA source files with OpenMP support

Tags: c++, cuda, openmp

It it possible to use OpenMP pragmas in CUDA source files (not in kernel code)?

I will combine GPU and CPU computation. But the nvcc compiler fails with "cannot find Unknown option 'openmp'", when I link the program with an `openmp` option (under Linux).

A workaround is to use OpenMP pragmas only in C/C++ files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've just found this

http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/miller/Courses/CSE710/heavner.pdf

Page 25 says:

> - With gcc:
>
>   - `#include` `omp.h`
>   - Add the `-fompenmp` [sic] flag
>
>     - With nvcc, this should be `-Xcompiler -fopenmp` as this needs to be passed directly to gcc
>     - `-Xcompiler` passes flags directly to host compiler
>   - Add `-lgomp` flag during the linking stage.

Note the misspelling of `-fopenmp` in the third line.

Answer (score 2):

I tried writing the parameter in "Additional Compiler Options" but it didn't work.

What I did for Visual Studio 2010 and CUDA 4.2:

In Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options:
-Xcompiler "/openmp"

This resulted in two -Xcompiler parameters in the resulting build command but did not cause any problems and worked successfully.

Answer (score 1):

### Building with CMake

I had to add `-Xcompiler=-fopenmp` as an compile option to my CMakeLists.txt file to build CUDA host code with OpenMP directives:

```
# your CMakeLists.txt should contain something like this already
project(<project> Languages CXX CUDA)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenMP)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")

# the following line was also necessary
target_compile_options(<target> PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>: -Xcompiler=-fopenmp>)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the Visual Studio found from the nvidia-forum:

add the '/openmp'-flag to the Extra C++ Options in cuda build rules. I will try the linux solution later.