# Specifying openmp CUDA flag in a Cmake project

Tags: cuda, cmake, openmp

How can I pass openmp flag to NVCC when in a cmake project? 
My CMakeLists.txt for this project looks like this, but compilation fails with "undefined reference to `omp_get_wtime'" message.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.2)

set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH 
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake" 
  ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
)

find_package (CUDA 4.0 REQUIRED)

if(OPENMP_FOUND)
 set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
 set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}
${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}") endif()

set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set (CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

if(UNIX)
  add_definitions(-DUNIX)
endif(UNIX)

add_subdirectory(xor)

CUDA_BUILD_CLEAN_TARGET()
```

Comment: Any option you want nvcc to pass on to the host compiler when you call it must go via the -Xcompiler option. So for gcc, -Xcompiler="-fopenmp" will turn on OpenMP compilation. How you make CMake do that, I don't know

Comment: I just found out that adding find_package (OpenMP) to the previous script did the trick. Simpler than I though.

Comment: I recommend putting these answers in an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that adding find_package (OpenMP) to the previous script did the trick.

Comment: I had to add a compile option; [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74388258/9845608)