# CUDA forces OpenMP to run in a single-threaded mode

Tags: c++, multithreading, cmake, cuda, openmp

I wrote a CUDA SGEMM program and when I wanted to test the speed with a multi-threading CPU implementation, it failed to run in a multi-threading way. I isolated the CPU implementation in a sperate `.cc` file, built it and ran it and there was no problem. The code in `.cu` and isolated `.cc` is (the same):

```cpp
void sgemm_cpu_multi_threading(
    float* A, float* B, float* C, 
    float alpha, float beta, const int M, const int N, const int K
) {
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
    for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
        printf("%d thread(s) can be used\n", omp_get_num_threads());
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
            float psum = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
                psum += A[m * K + k] * B[k * N + n];
            }
            C[m * N + n] = C[m * N + n] * beta + psum * alpha;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(OMP_THREADS);   // OMP_THREADS=8
    // ... 
    sgemm_cpu_multi_threading(A, B, C, alpha, beta, M, N, K);
    // ...
}
```

In the CUDA program, the printf always outputs "**1 thread(s) can be used**" and the execution is indeed serialized. While isolated pure cxx executable tells me "**8 thread(s) can be used**".
The CMakeLists.txt of mine (CUDA). For the isolated cxx project, I only delete lines related to CUDA.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(SGEMM CUDA CXX)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
endif()

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "$ENV{CXXFLAGS} -O3 -Wall -fopenmp")
SET(COMPILE_CUDA True)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 75)

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
  set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
  set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()

include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../
)

add_executable(matmul ./matmul.cu)

target_link_libraries(matmul pthread OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
```

Can somebody tell me what's going on here? Why can't I properly use OpenMP multi-threading in a CUDA program? BTW, if you wish to know, the A, B, C can be allocated using `new` or `cudaMallocHost` and it won't affect the fact that I can't not run the program with more than one thread, even if **the CPU function should be seperated by nvcc and compile & run on CPU.**

Comment: you might have compiled things incorrectly.  when compiling CUDA codes with `nvcc` that use OpenMP, its generally necessary to pass specific compile switches to `nvcc`, inlcluding for example (if on linux) `-Xcompiler -fopenmp`.  I have no idea if your Cmake is doing this or not, but I would definitely tag this question with `cmake`.

Comment: you can find an example of how to build an OpenMP code with `nvcc` in the [CUDA samples](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/0_Introduction/cudaOpenMP) (although not with cmake).

Comment: It is always helpful to check the actual compile commands used with `make VERBOSE=1`. That shows that `-fopenmp` is not passed to `nvcc`. In the `if (OPENMP_FOUND)` conditional you are only changing options for the `CXX` and `C` languages, not for the `CUDA` language. `set (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -Xcompiler ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")` seems to work for me in terms of adding `-Xcompiler -fopenmp` to the compile command. Although this could be fragile as it depends on `OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS` being a single flag. A less fragile solution would require some more string fiddling.

Comment: [`--forward-unknown-to-host-compiler`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html?highlight=Xcompiler#forward-unknown-to-host-compiler-forward-unknown-to-host-compiler) might be a way of adding those flags without worrying about `-Xcompiler`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using openMP in the cuda host code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211614/using-openmp-in-the-cuda-host-code)

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks, it turns out to be the problem of CMake configuration. I removed CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and CMAKE_C_FLAGS, and instead added `set (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")`, omp multi-threading could be supported even without `-Xcompiler` and `-fopenmp` (I guess `${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}` includes some of them?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @RobertCrovella, my code is not compiled properly, with `CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS` not properly set. Solution is quite straight-forward, use:

```
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
  set (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()
```

instead of setting c and cxx flags in the CMake. I checked the content of `${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}` via `message` and it writes `-fopenmp` (and nothing else), so one doesn't need to write `-fopenmp` again. Also, I can compile the code without `-Xcompiler` and it runs correctly. Should the problem persist, one can try adding this flag. Thanks for the comments by @RobertCrovella and @paleonix.